# Error using torch.normal with invalid combination of arguments

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, invalid-argument

I got some error when using `torch.normal`

I don't know what is the problem.

```
torch.normal(mean=0,std=1,size=(128,100)).cuda()

 TypeError: normal() received an invalid combination of arguments - got (std=int, mean=int, size=tuple, ), but expected one of:
 * (Tensor mean, Tensor std, torch.Generator generator, Tensor out)
 * (Tensor mean, float std, torch.Generator generator, Tensor out)
 * (float mean, Tensor std, torch.Generator generator, Tensor out)
```

What is the problem?

Comment: The problem same happen when I use float number for mean and std

Comment: which torch version are you using?

Comment: I use 1.1.0 version. should I upgrade to 1.4.0?